Is there a way to use a typescript and bootstrap component library in a Blazor App?
I am looking to build a component library for my company using Bootstrap and Typescript then deploying it as a nuget package.  I figure this will give us the most flexibility without starting from zero and blazor at times is restrictive when I need to do more.
The issue is my company still wants to use blazor for our web apps.  So my question is can I even do this within reason and what does that entail? If I have to build the library with blazor so be it but trying to do better for the team.

I don't understand.. So you need some kind of blazor wrapper around ts/bootstrap component?

I am just wondering how feasible it is to build a ts and bootstrap component library that blazor ui apps with consume and use  and how to go about it or if it is more hassle than its worth and it would be better to just build it in blazor? My research has been less than helpful so far.

It is feasible. You can create your component in TypeScript and build a Blazor wrapper around it. There are many such solutions—just search for "Blazor wrapper." However, these are for "components" where the JavaScript implementation already exists. If you go this route, you will create extra work for yourself.
